# Load php function onClick

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Javascript**

```
$("#ReadTok").click(function(){
    $("#tokentype").load('../process/read_token_type.php');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="Readtok" value="Read Token" />
<span id="tokentype"></span>
```

**PHP**

```
echo $PartType;
```

This has worked perfectly for me before why is it not working now.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: id='Readtok' , $("#ReadTok"). Notice the T

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your javascript with this one

```
$("#Readtok").click(function(){  //here t is small letter in ReadTok
    $("#tokentype").load('../process/read_token_type.php');
});
```

Because your button id is `id="Readtok"`

Comment: That is exactly the same?????

Comment: @ErichNiemand No, both are not same, ids are case sensitive.

Comment: Sorry I a Naveen I am a rank amateur.

Answer (score 0):

A typo error. `ReadTok` vs `Readtok`

```
$("#ReadTok").click(function(){
    $("#tokentype").load('../process/read_token_type.php');
});
```

Comment: thank you totally missed that

Answer (score 0):

Your ID and Function Selector Name is mismatch thats the problem correct it sure it will work

```
$("#Readtok").click(function(){
    $("#tokentype").load('../process/read_token_type.php');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here one solution.

```
<Html>
     <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Readtok").click(function () {
                $("#tokentype").load('../process/read_token_type.php');
            });
        });
     </script>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="Readtok" value="Read Token" />
<span id="tokentype"></span>

</body>

</html>
```

I hope to help

Answer (score 0):

the `id` attribute is case  sensitive so `Readtok` and `ReadTok` are different

either change your javascript to this :

```
$("#Readtok").click(function(){
    $("#tokentype").load('../process/read_token_type.php');
});
```

or else chage id :

`id="Readtok"` to `id="ReadTok"` without altering your javascript